# How to fix AddType or AddHandler problems

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, htaccess, php5

I recently moved from an old Godaddy hosting account to a new Godaddy Cpanel hosting account.

The menus on the website are generated by using php include statements which worked on the old hosting account. However, on this new hosting the php include statement do not work & if you click on a link on the website the dialog to save a file open instead of the html link opening a webpage. The server is Deluxe Linux Hosting with cPanel running Apache php 5.3. This is the htaccess that worked on the old hosting account, How do i fix this problem?

```
#simple ETag
FileETag MTime Size

# Turn on the Expires engine
ExpiresActive On

# Expires after a month client accesses the file
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
ExpiresByType text/plain A2592000

# Good for one week
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript M604800
ExpiresByType text/css M604800
ExpiresByType text/html M604800
# Compress entire website
<IfModule deflate_module>
    # Enable compression for the following file types.
    AddOutputFilterByType            \
     DEFLATE                         \
      application/javascript         \
      text/css                       \
      text/html                      \
      text/javascript                \
      text/plain                     \
      text/xml
</IfModule>
#
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
AddHandler x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```